# Mysql - transfer data between tables based on search form

Tags: mysql, search

Trying to transfer data between 2 tables based on search form input and several other criteria.

This is Table1:

```
Name    Company     Card_nr
John    Microsoft   12345
Mike    Oracle      11223
Alex    Tesla       13345
```

This is Table2:

```
Device_id    Check_in   Check_out   Device_status        Name   Company    Card_nr    Device_priority
1            Date       Date           1("Available")    John   Microsoft  12345            1
2            Date       Date           2("Unavailable")
3            Date       Date           3("In use")
4            Date       Date           1                 Mike   Oracle     11223            0 
5            Date       Date           2
6            Date       Date           3
```

Search form is based on `Card_nr`.

If `Card_nr` is not found in `Table1`, then write `Card_nr` to `Table1` and do the following:

While `Card_nr` is found in `Table1`, search `Card_nr` also in `Table2`.

If `Card_nr` is in `Table2` and `Device_priority=1` and `Device_status=1` then write `Date` to `Check_in`, and overwrite `Name, Company, Card_nr from Table1` to `Table2` on the line that matches `Card_nr`.

If `Card_nr` is in Table2 and `Device_priority=1` and Device_status **not 1** then display message.

If `Card_nr` is in `Table2` and `Device_priority=0` then write `Date to Check_in and overwrite Name, Company, Card_nr from Table1` to first line(Based on Device_id) that has `Device_status=1`("Available")

If `Card_n`r is not in `Table2`, then write `Date` to `Check_in` and overwrite `Name, Company, Card_nr from Table1` to first line that has `Device_status=1`.

If there is no line with `Device_status=1` then display message.

If my query is too complicated, I can break it down in separate issues.

Comment: It would be useful if you could add the table schema and sample data

Comment: I have edited it, it`s table1. But the code that I`ve quoted is just a simple search form that just displays search results, it doesn`t do anything else.

Comment: I can tell that the code posted doesn't really do much but posting the actual code rather than a facsimile usually gives a better picture of what is going on. Do you really have tables named `table1` and `table2`?

Comment: I have edited again and removed the code, as it was just causing confusion.
I do not really have tables named table1 and table2, these names are given as examples.
I have several bits of code, but none related to the query at hand.
Like previously mentioned, any kind of help is welcome.

Comment: so far you have not tried anything and have not updated your question to include the db schema so this looks like a code writing request and nothing more. In theory the requirements are quite straightforward - have a crack at it and when you get stuck post the code and explain what went wrong.

Comment: Guidelines clearly indicate that a user can ask questions about "a software algorithm", but maybe I misjudged this.
I wasn`t expecting anybody to write the code for me, just some basic guidelines.